# Lucene searching stack traces: splitting on dots

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I'm writing an app that embeds Lucene to search for, amongst other things, parts of stack traces, including class names etc. For example, if a document contained:

`java.lang.NullPointerException`

The documents can also contain ordinary English text.

I'd like to be able to query for either `NullPointerException` or `java.lang.NullPointerException` and find the document. Using the `StandardAnalyzer`, I only get a match if I search for the full `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

What's the best way to go about supporting this? Can I get multiple tokens emitted? e.g. `java`, `lang`, `NullPointerException` and `java.lang.NullPointerException`? Or would I be better replacing all the `.` characters with spaces up front? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dot character is considered an ["ambiguous terminator"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#SB5) for the purposes of the algorithm used by `StandardAnalyzer`.  Lucene attempts to be intelligent about this and make the best possible guess for the situation.

You have a couple of options here:

- If you don't want Lucene to apply a bunch of complicated lexical tokenization rules, you can try a simpler analyzer, such as `SimpleAnalyzer`, which will just create tokens of uninterrupted strings of letters.
- Implement a filter that applies your own specialized rules, and incorporate it into an Analyzer similar to the `StandardAnalyzer`.  This would allow you to test whatever identification techniques you like to recognize that a token is an exception, and split them up during the analysis phase.
- As you said, you can replace the periods with spaces before they ever hit the analyzer at all.